# Ghost columns in SQL query results sent as text

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2014

In SQL Server 2014, I wrote a query into a table. If I chose "Results to Grid", the results are listed column by column as the order as the table.

However, if I send "Results to Text", the results are listed with some extra ghost columns. I say "ghost" because those empty columns are between actual columns.

I did not lose any actual columns but there are some ghost or empty columns that occupy some column spaces. They do not show anything in the column header or column. Just take space that look like some column. I cannot resize them but have to use the horizontal scroll bar to view some columns.

There was one thing I did that might contributed to this. After the table was created I modified some columns, added a new columns and rearranged their orders. But the "Results to Grid" all reflected those change correctly. Only "Results to Text" show those ghost columns.

Comment: can you paste the text result?  have you imported table values from another db?

Answer (score 0):

That because `tab` character or other special character such as CRLF exist in the field value, especially in char types.. this code below demonstrate that kind of behavior..

```
SELECT 1 A, 'normal long long long long long text' B, 1 C, 1 D, 1 E
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'test' + CHAR(9)  + 'multi-column', 2, 2, 2
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'test
break line
text', 3, 3, 3
UNION ALL
SELECT 4 A, 'other normal' B, 4 C, 4 D, 4 E
```

when use `Results to Grid` it looks normal, but when change to `Results to Text` the result becomes messy

```
A           B                                    C           D           E
----------- ------------------------------------ ----------- ----------- -----------
1           normal long long long long long text 1           1           1
2           test    multi-column                    2           2           2
3           test
    break line
    text             3           3           3
4           other normal                         4           4           4

(4 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Susilo. After reading this I rechecked the table and found that the "ghost" columns are after column with type "varchar(50)" and type "text" which has a very wide empty column area following it. In fact those "ghost" columns are not really column but extended column space of preceding columns. I tried a few Output formats for "Results to Text". I could trim the column headers to fit the width of the column names but rows of records will not align with their column header except the case of using Column aligned choice. I guess I have to live with it. At least for now.